# Searching for pattern that does not start with alphanumeric character

Tags: regex, vim

I want search for a pattern in vim that does not start with alphanumeric character. This means a pattern that starts with space and start of new line as well.
If {pattern} = noremap
I tried to search by `/\Wnoremap`, but it misses the latter case since it expects at least one character before the pattern.
I know `/^noremap` would work, but I want to how I can combine the both cases together.

Comment: have you tried /\<noremap?

Comment: cool, what is the meaning of `\<`?

Comment: it means match the beginning of the word next specified, more or less.  I personally don't know the specifics.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [vimregex](http://vimregex.com/):

IV. Pattern Description

4.1 Anchors

\< and \> are anchors.

You can read more about them at the link.

Comment: Just "anchors" by itself is a little vague, they're special word boundary anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
/\(^\|\W\)noremap
```

`^\|\W` means either `^` or `\W`.
The `()` (escaped with `\`) is just so that it isn't `^` or `\Wnoremap`.

Negative look-behind (`@<!`) may also work:

```
/\(@<!\W\)noremap
```

[Reference](http://vimregex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

EHuhtala answered my question, but I wanted to put an explanation:
`\>` is the beginning of a word.
It's reference can be found on vim under `ordinary-atom`

```
:h oridnary-atom
```